# Match '%' sign when searching in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I would like to match this `'wildcard %'` in MySQL.
I tried using escape `\%` and it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default escape character is `\`. So just prefix `%` with a `\` as: `\%`:

The [**manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) clearly says:

> To test for literal instances of a
>   wild-card character, precede it by the
>   escape character. If you do not
>   specify the ESCAPE character, “\” is
>   assumed.

Search for `%` in `Stack%Overflow`:

```
mysql> select 'Stack%Overflow' like '%\%%';
+------------------------------+
| 'Stack%Overflow' like '%\%%' |
+------------------------------+
|                            1 |  <----- Found
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Search for `%` in `StackOverflow`:

```
mysql> select 'StackOverflow' like '%\%%';
+-----------------------------+
| 'StackOverflow' like '%\%%' |
+-----------------------------+
|                           0 |   <----- Not Found
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT:**

If you are calling this query from PHP, you'll have to use `\\`. This is because even PHP uses `\` as the escape character. So make MySQL get a `\` you need to have `\\` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE fieldName LIKE "wildcard\%"';
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i need to use doble `(\\)` to match the % in the database

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the \ in PHP string as well, otherwise PHP would think that you are actually escaping the %, thus sending literal % to the sql query, so I think this should work:

```
mysql_query("select * from bla where bli like '\\%somewords\\%'");
```

Comment: You'd only have to double escape if you were using double-quoted (`"`) strings. As is, your version will search for literal backslashes with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version you can also try

```
select * from tbl1 where TxtExpr REGEXP '^%';
```

regards