# Why Mysqli prepared statement does'nt escape wildcards (% and _) and Backslash ( \ )?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

As a security measure I am using Mysqli prepared statement and bindvariables.

My code is shown below:

```
$what = trim($_GET['what']);
$key_word = "%".$what."%";  
$where_clause = " WHERE chair.company LIKE ? OR chair.business_category LIKE ? OR chair.summary LIKE ?";
$query = "SELECT chair.id_user, chair.company   FROM chair" . $where_clause; 
$con = @mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password, $database_name);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $key_word, $key_word, $key_word);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$business_id,$company);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    {
    echo htmlspecialchars($company)."<br>";
    }
```

From [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html):

> As an alternative to explicitly escaping special characters, many MySQL APIs provide a placeholder capability that enables you to insert special markers into a statement string, and then bind data values to them when you issue the statement. In this case, the API takes care of escaping special characters in the values for you.

I can use all character in the keyboard (excluding   \ %  _ ) and  escaped and  matched properly.
My problem is that this prepared statement does not escaping wild cards(% and _) and escape character (\). When I am searching for %  It lists all item in the database. And When Iam searching for _  It lists all items .
And when searching for (\), It doesn't match the desired item.

I had find a [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038716/what-characters-are-not-escaped-with-a-mysqli-prepared-statement?rq=1), but the amswer never meet  my requirement because I have to use the wildcard with my query.

[Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352232/match-sign-when-searching-in-mysql-database) answer says that to escape them use double back slashes

Even this is not a security issue, why prepared statement doesn't escape them?
Is there any mistake in the way Iam using it in my code?
How to dynamically escape them ? Which function can I use for it?

Comment: %: They are part of the LIKE statement; if they were escaped, they would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statements *do* escape the `\` properly. Otherwise they wouldn’t create properly formatted [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html), which is the main purpose of prepared statements.

Besides that, `%` and `_` are only special characters to the [`LIKE` comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) but not to strings in general. So there is no need to escape them in general. If you need to escape them for a `LIKE` comparison, do it explicitly:

```
$what = addcslashes($what, '%_');
```

Besides that, [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) does also support the use of an escape character other than `\`:

```
mysql> SELECT 'David_' LIKE 'David|_' ESCAPE '|';
        -> 1
```